# Do objects stay in the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

If I create a new thread

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new myRunnableClass());
thread.start();
```

and inside the thread I do

```
new mySecondRunnableClass().run();
```

will the second runnable class now be running inside the first thread?

Comment: Objects are not inside threads as such. You can describe an object as visible to a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new mySecondRunnableClass().run();
```

You are just creating a new instance of your `Runnable` instance and calling `run()` on it. It will be executed in same thread i.e `Thread thread = new Thread(new myRunnableClass());`. If you are concerned about the instance memory location than it is always created on heap and it's reference will be on `thread` private stack.

Answer (score 0):

> will the second runnable class now be running inside the first thread?

There is no such place as "inside [a] thread".  A thread does not have an inside or an outside.  And, in Java in particular, a thread does not even have a parent thread or child threads.

Threads just are.

If your program's main thread starts a new thread, then you program will have two threads, and the two threads are *peers* in every way.  Neither one owns the other, neither one controls the other.

The only special relationship between them is that the main thread must know about the new thread ('cause after all, the main thread started it,) but the new thread does not necessarily know about the main thread.  Whether or not it actually *does* know about the main thread is entirely up to you.

If the second thread starts a third thread...  Same deal.  Now your program has three threads, and they are all peers.